# Автоматическое включение плагина после установки в Joomla! 3.x

Tags: xml, joomla, расширения

Есть ли способ автоматически включать плагин после установки в Joomla 3.x? Может быть есть некий спец. параметр, типа `enabled="1"` для манифеста .xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, единственный способ это осуществить - делать запрос в БД после установки для изменения состояния плагина, т.к. в документации Joomla! нет упоминаний о таком параметре для манифеста.